# How to extend User Class from Spring Security and use JPA to create the table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to get the attributes from User and Authorities provided by Spring Security.

I know that you can override the UserDetailsService in order to make your own custom class but in this case I want to get the full default class and ,additionally , a few more attributes.

Let me explain with the code:

```
public class User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

private String password;
private final String username;
private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
private final boolean accountNonExpired;
private final boolean accountNonLocked;
private final boolean credentialsNonExpired;
private final boolean enabled; 
}
```

This is the User class that Spring Security provide and what I want is to extends my own class using those attributes.
I tried this but the database doesn't get the attributes from User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyUser")

public class ExtendedUser extends User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String email;


  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2147191899215904479L;

  public ExtendedUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
        boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
.
.
.
```

My question is, Do I need to create my own User class in order to inherit those attributes and use the JPA annotations to make Hibernate "understand" it?

I think I'm missleading something here but I can't figure it.

Comment: so is "User" annotated as an entity? And if not, then you follow JPA docs and map it using an _orm.xml_ file.

Comment: No , is not.
I don't want to mix the XML Config with the Java Config that i'm currently using and ,because this, i can't add that annotation to the User class since it's inside a library.

i think i will use the way that Naros described.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You do not need to extend User class from Spring Security. The cleaner and simpler solution is to let your ExtendedUser class to implement UserDetails interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JPA, map it in *orm.xml* or in Hibernate, you could use the deprecated *HBM xml*.

I would actually recommend not extending an entity mapping from the Spring Security `User` class as it makes your mappings very coupled with their implementation, which you have no control over and could make upgrading that more difficult.

Instead, I'd recommend you create your own `User` entity and store the information in a model that suits your application's needs.  Then as a part of the `UserDetailsService` implementation, you take your `User` entity and related entities and construct an extended `UserDetails` object which you give to Spring Security.

Comment: Yeah, i know that you can override the Service to map your own custom class tto work with Spring Security (Instead of UserName , you can map it to email , for example).
But what you said makes sense, it's something you want control of.

As i thought, i was missleading some concepts , Spring do too many things for you but ... that's the idea!

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the Getter/Setter to add the JPA's annotations on it.